# Algorithm to determine the order of items based on weighted values

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm not even sure where to start with this type of issue, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a list of items, each with four attributes. The attributes are weighed in favor, for instance, attribute 1 is more important than attribute 2, etc.

I was hoping to find an algorithm or equation of some sort to order these items based on these values. Thoughts?

Comment: what's wrong with the [standard sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)?

Comment: haha...nothing if that's the best way to do it. Like I mentioned...I didn't even know where to start. I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: Implement your own comparer and use standard sorting algorithms..

Answer (score 6):

You should use a [regular sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), only difference is your comparator, that saying `x<y` is more complex, and should be something like the following pseudo code:

```
compare(x,y) {
   if (x.attribute1 < y.attribute1) return -1
   if (x.attribute1 > y.attribute1) return 1
   if (x.attribute2 < y.attribute2) return -1
   if (x.attribute2 > y.attribute2) return 1
   if (x.attribute3 < y.attribute3) return -1
   if (x.attribute3 > y.attribute3) return 1
   if (x.attribute4 < y.attribute4) return -1
   if (x.attribute4 > y.attribute4) return 1
   return 0
}
```

An alternative is to use [stable sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), and repeat the sorting for each attribute, starting from the least important, and ending with the most important.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort (lexicographically) your things for example:

1234
1244
1312

You can use [Radix algorith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) .